# DAX - Calculate which item has the max value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 tables in my model.

A fact table:

Passengers

| Date | ServiceUID | StationID | PassengerCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13/05/2021 | a1 | aaa | 30 |
| 13/05/2021 | a1 | bbb | 21 |
| 13/05/2021 | a1 | ccc | 11 |
| 13/05/2021 | a2 | ddd | 25 |
| 13/05/2021 | a2 | eee | 14 |
| 13/05/2021 | a2 | ccc | 12 |
| 12/05/2021 | a1 | aaa | 10 |
| 12/05/2021 | a1 | bbb | 12 |
| 12/05/2021 | a1 | ccc | 13 |
| 12/05/2021 | a2 | ddd | 14 |
| 12/05/2021 | a2 | eee | 13 |
| 12/05/2021 | a2 | ccc | 13 |

And two dimensions:

Stations

| StationID | Station Name | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | aaaaaa | Region 1 |
| bbb | bbbbbb | Region 1 |
| ccc | cccccc | Region 2 |
| ddd | dddddd | Region 3 |
| eee | eeeeee | Region 3 |

Service

| ServiceUID | Service Name |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | aaa to ccc |
| a2 | ddd to ccc |

I want to write a measure in DAX that will show me, depending on how I slice the data, which Service Name had the most passengers (a simple sum of the PassengerCount column)

Split by Region

| Region | Busiest Service |
| --- | --- |
| Region 1 | aaa to ccc |
| Region 2 | ddd to ccc |
| Region 3 | ddd to ccc |

or by Date

| Date | Busiest Service |
| --- | --- |
| 12/05/2021 | ddd to ccc |
| 13/05/2021 | aaa to ccc |

I'm pretty new to DAX and I can't see how I would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume you have created relationships between tables. (It's a good idea to have the Calendar table as another dimension, especially if you have more fact tables that you want to filter.

```
MostPassenger = 

var __innerTab = SELECTCOLUMNS(TOPn(1,ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES(Services[Service Name]), "Sum", CALCULATE(SUM(Passenger[PassengerCount]))),[Sum],DESC), "Service", Services[Service Name])
return
__innerTab
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that did it